# how to save an array value using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a bean of type string[] which has two or more values. I want to save the array:

```
user.setItem(item[i]);
session.beginTransaction();
session.save(user);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

But I am getting only one data item saved not the entire array .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Annotation, do as follows (Use List instead of Array)

```
@Entity
public class User {

    private List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @CollectionOfElements
    @JoinTable(name="TABLE_ITEM")
    private List<String> getItemList() {
        return this.itemList;
    }

}
```

And do as follows

```
User user = (User) sessionFactory.openSession().get(User.class, userId);

user.getItemList().add(item);
```

Because you have a managed Entity instance (User) and the lifecycle of a value-type instance (your String list) is bound to that of its owning entity instance (User). Hibernate will save your new item.